# JavaScript combining three 2D arrays, keeping first values unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, underscore.js

I have three 2D arrays as such, where the first value in each sub array within each 2D array is unique to that array.  However, some of these arrays might be missing values.

**Example:**

```
var a = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 20]];
var b = [[1, 20], [2, 10]];
var c = [[2, 30]];
```

Array `a` has values for 1, 2, and 3, but array `b` only has values for 1 and 2, and array `c` only has a value for 2.

I want to combine these three arrays into a new final array, let's say `d`.  Array `d` should only contain one of each first value, so for example, the three arrays above would combine into.

```
d = [[1, 10, 20], [2, 20, 10, 30], [3, 20]];
```

**My first *half-arsed* attempt:**

I can combine the three arrays into one with `concat`:

```
a = a.concat(b, c);
// a = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 20], [1, 20], [2, 10], [2, 30]];
```

But then I'm not sure how to combine non-unique elements.  I've looked into some of `underscore`'s functions, and I couldn't really find one that would help (although I am **very** new to underscore).

**My second attempt:**

```
// First combine just a and b
for(var ai = 0; ai < a.length; ai++) {
  var inserted = false;
  for(var bi = 0; bi < b.length; bi++) {
    if(a[ai][0] == b[bi][0]) {
      d.push([(a[ai][0]), (a[ai][1]), (b[bi][1])]);
      inserted = true;
    }
  }
  if(!inserted) {
    d.push([(a[ai][0]), (a[ai][1])]);
  }
}
// Then repeat the above with d and c
```

The problem with this solution was that if `a` had less elements than `b`, the result won't include the elements of `b` that `a` didn't have.  I could write a ridiculous series of loops, but that would just be woefully inefficient, and making so many JSON calls is already taking a toll on the website speed.

Comment: Your "attempt" is... kinda half-arsed, don't you think?

Comment: Alright then... I'll add my other attempt.

Comment: Why don't you use objects to do this ? Seems like the first elements of the sub-arrays should be keys : `var a = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 20};`, `var b = {1: 20, 2: 10};`, `var c = {2: 30};`. That would be easier to combine it then.

Comment: I didn't know that objects are easier to combine than arrays- how so?  I could solve it this way, the arrays `a`, `b`, and `c` are actually JSON objects that I convert into arrays to put into a d3 graph.

Comment: How do you get the data in the first place?

Comment: I make three separate JSON calls for three different "sources", that return three different 2D arrays.  The arrays are actually 2D arrays of time in milliseconds and a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
var a = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 20]];
var b = [[1, 20], [2, 10]];
var c = [[2, 30]];

var d = a.concat(b,c);
var e = [];
//loop through all the inner arrays
//the first item in each array is considered as key
//the second is considered as value and should be pushed into some array 
//which can be accessed via the key.
for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i++){    
  if(!e[d[i][0]]) e[d[i][0]] = [d[i][0]];    
  e[d[i][0]].push(d[i][1]);
}

d = [];
for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
  if(e[i]) d.push(e[i]);
}

console.log(d);
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/xb3Ku/)

Comment: Awesome.  I don't quite understand what the very last `for loop` is doing.  It's looping through `e`, and checking if the element exists, and then pushing it into `d`?  I looked at the `console.log`s of both, and saw the two results were formatted slightly differently.

Comment: @Hubrid the result `e` may contain different indices such as we may have `e[0]`, `e[2]` but not have `e[1]` (or `undefined`), so we need to convert it to another array to normalize indices (from `0` to `1`). However in your example, they are nearly the same (except that the first item of `e` is `undefined`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function concat(first, second) {
    var result = [],
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        k = 1;

    if (second.length > first.length) {
        result = second.slice();
        first = first.slice();
    } else {
        result = first.slice();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < second.length; j++) {
            if (result[i][0] === second[j][0]) {
                for (k = 1; k < second[j].length; k++) {
                    result[i].push(second[j][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first element in each subarray is unique then why don't you write it like this instead:

```
var a = { 1: [10], 2: [20], 3: [20] };
var b = { 1: [20], 2: [10] };
var c = { 2: [30] };
```

Actually let's write a function to do this:

```
var a = mapFrom2DArray([[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 20]]);
var b = mapFrom2DArray([[1, 20], [2, 10]]);
var c = mapFrom2DArray([[2, 30]]);

function mapFrom2DArray(array) {
    var map = {}, length = array.length, index = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var subarray = array[index++];
        map[subarray[0]] = subarray.slice(1);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Now let's write a combinator which takes two maps and combines them:

```
function combine(a, b) {
    var c = {};

    for (var k in a) c[k] = a[k];

    for (var k in b) {
        if (c.hasOwnProperty(k))
            c[k] = c[k].concat(b[k]);
        else c[k] = b[k];
    }

    return c;
}
```

Now we simply `reduce` the maps:

```
var d = mapToArray([a, b, c].reduce(combine));
```

Oh, and the definition of `mapToArray`:

```
function mapToArray(map) {
    var array = [];
    for (var k in map) array.push([parseInt(k)].concat(map[k]));
    return array;
}
```

That's all. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/56B6T/1